# Dagger2 : Is it possible to use injection with inject() and @Inject from a dependent Component?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I manage to use injection with declaring a *ChildObject childObject()* method in the dependent Component interface and using *myParentComponent.childObject()* in the consumer class.

I have tried to use the standard way *void inject(Main mainActivity)* declaration and @Inject in the consumer class and it does not work :

> Error:(7, 10) error: com.jgl.dagger2dependentcomponent.ChildModule.ChildObject >cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or >@Produces-annotated method.
>   com.jgl.dagger2dependentcomponent.MainActivity.childObject
>   [injected field of type: com.jgl.dagger2dependentcomponent.ChildModule.ChildObject childObject]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Inject
    ChildModule.ChildObject childObject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParentComponent parentComponent = DaggerParentComponent.builder().parentModule(new ParentModule()).build();
        ChildComponent childComponent = DaggerChildComponent.builder().parentComponent(parentComponent).childModule(new ChildModule()).build();
        childComponent.inject(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "childObject is null : " + (childObject == null ? "true" : "false"));
    }
}
```

Parent Component

```
package com.jgl.dagger2dependentcomponent;

import dagger.Component;

@Component(modules=ParentModule.class)
public interface ParentComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    ParentModule.ParentObject parentObject();
}
```

ParentModule

```
package com.jgl.dagger2dependentcomponent;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class ParentModule {

    @Provides
    ParentObject providesParentObject(){
        return new ParentObject();
    }

    public static class ParentObject{}
}
```

ChildComponent

```
package com.jgl.dagger2dependentcomponent;

import dagger.Component;

@Component(dependencies = ParentComponent.class, modules = ChildModule.class)
public interface ChildComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

ChildModule

```
package com.jgl.dagger2dependentcomponent;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class ChildModule {

    @Provides
    ChildObject providesChildObject(ParentModule.ParentObject parentObject){
        return new ChildObject(parentObject);
    }

    public static class ChildObject{
        private ParentModule.ParentObject parentObject;

        public ChildObject(ParentModule.ParentObject parentObject) {
            this.parentObject = parentObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You pasted the child component where you say it is the parent component.

Comment: Your **ParentComponent** class is missing

Comment: It is now corrected, thank you.

Comment: make the ChildComponent extend ParentComponent, and remove the duplicate inject(MainActivity) from one of them.

Comment: It hasn't resolved the problem.

Commenting the inject in the ParentComponent makes it work, but it doesn't permit anymore to use the inject with ParentComponent.
Do you see a solution ?